# Groovy Script with API returning error 401

Tags: api, rest, authentication, groovy, http-status-code-401

I have this groovy script where I need to call API using the method GET.
When I call it on Postman, it works nicely, however I am getting the 401 error when I try to run it in Groovy Script.

```
package kikoloko
def token = "myToken"

def connection = new URL("URL").openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer ${token}")
connection.connect()

println(connection.getInputStream().getText())
```

Error:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code:

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Comment: Tried your code in https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/ and it works fine. The problem might be your token -> it should be Base64 encoded

Comment: @injecteer, I have added "def encoded = token.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()", and I'm still getting the same error, I also tried without the ".toString()", and I got the same thing.

Comment: can you check the server's log? Maybe your token expired or is invalid in some way? Again, I tested your code against my server and it technically worked fine.

Comment: @injecteer the code is working fine as well, I believe that could be something related with the API Key I'm using.

Comment: @injecteer I manage it to work removing the the header from my API, the problem wasn't on the script, it was on my API. Thanks for the assistance